# Problem in filter when we using Table with filtering in material using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using mat-table. It has a filter which works not proper.

Filter not working against the data below.

it does not filter the data according to a customer object and also not worked for _id and all the data was filter perfectly.

Sample Data:

```
{
  advance: 100
  balance: 400
  category: "Suit"
  cloth_material: "febric "
  cloth_measurements: "5m"
  completion_date: "2019-03-21T18:30:00.000Z"
  createdAt: "2019-03-26T09:00:51.362Z"
  customer: {name: "Riya", phone_number: "9711280827"}
  design_photo: "vbnvb"
  febric_photo: "vnb"
  fit_type: "Standard Fit"
  measurement_type: "Inch",
  order_status: "InProcess"
  order_taken_by: "dsfsdf"
  price: 500
  remarks: "nhbghjghj"
  tailor: "SRS"
  user: "5c99ddfce7aebc28fc8ef4a7"
  __v: 0
  _id: 2
}
```

TS Code:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: any) {
  filterValue = filterValue.trim();
  filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  this.orderData.filter = filterValue;

  if (this.orderData.paginator) {
    this.orderData.paginator.firstPage();
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

So how we filter data according to the above data.
I want to search for all the data within orderData.

Comment: this is object, and not an array

Comment: If possible then provide [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qkjxonxryral?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts) example

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewqcf-fbx88m?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html .
filter dose not work for customer name.

Comment: @AakankshiGupta Are you showing this data on HTML Page?

Comment: @AakankshiGupta Check this: Have modified: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewqcf-zuvvs6

Comment: thanku so much @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Is it working...?

Comment: yes its working for me.

Comment: @AakankshiGupta Have posted as an answer!

Comment: Hii are you there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataSource's `filterPredicate` method to implement your custom filter so change your `applyFilter()` as below:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) => {
    const managedList = (currentTerm, key) => {
      return key === 'customer' ? currentTerm + data.customer.name : currentTerm + data[key];
    };
    const value = Object.keys(data).reduce(managedList, '').toLowerCase();
    const customeFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
    return value.indexOf(customeFilter) !== -1;
  };
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewqcf-zuvvs6)